Override (reintroduce) property with typescript declaration merging
The base/built-in declaration of Event and GlobalEventHandlersEventMap looks like so:
// lib.dom.d.ts

interface Event {
    /**
     * Returns the type of event, e.g. "click", "hashchange", or "submit".
     */
    readonly type: string;   // <-- note this part
}

interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
    click: MouseEvent;
    //... all sorts of other built in events...
}

Let's say I define an EventTriggered whose constructor has a parameter containing one of the properties named in GlobalEventHandlersEventMap:
class EventTriggered {
    constructor(
        readonly eventName: keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap
    ) {}
}

This means that the following works because there is a property named 'click':
new EventTriggered('click');

But the following will not work (this is ok and intended):
new EventTriggered('some-random-string');

Now I want to use this class inside an event listener, like so:
function onClick(event: Event): void {
    new EventTriggered(event.type);
}

This will fail because as in the first example, event.type contains "any string". Type casting could be one way of solving this:
function onClick(event: Event): void {
    new EventTriggered(event.type as keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap);
}

BUT in my opinion, the original declaration of type is wrong - it should not be string, but keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap.
I tried doing that with declaration merging:
// global.d.ts
interface Event {
    readonly type: keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap;
}

What happens then is that the previous error still shows up, but now my IDE shows that type has two declarations:


I also saw this question, but it feels different - for one thing, I'm not getting the same error as that one: TypeScript declaration merging - changing a property type

Well, declaration merging is not something I personally consider a feature but rather a bug :)
If I understand correctly you want to have an union type which will be taken from key names of EventMap but there sometimes may be some other string which is not a part of key names union.
You can replace
readonly eventName: keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap

With
readonly eventName: string

But this approach makes you lose all key names information.
You can instead do a little trick that typescript have like below.
readonly eventName: keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap | ({} & string)

This way eventName will be key names or any other string. Also auto complete will work for this variable.

Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question. I tried to explain how declaration merging works but that made my problem confusing. I'll simplify my question.

I've updated the question. In the last sample, it could be simplified to eventName: keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap | string, no? In any case, that's not something I want...the field has to be a key of that map, otherwise there's no point.

It will not work at all with declaration merging.
Why you dont write types recursively like below?
interface Test {
  name: keyof Tests
}

interface Tests {
  a: Test
  b: Test
}


Not sure how that relates - can you give a more practical/complete example?
Keep in mind that Event, GlobalEventHandlersEventMap and the event object (and its type property) are built-in, and the only way I can change them (AFAIK) is with decl. merging.

That said, I could suggest to the TS dom lib maintainers to update the declaration of event.type on their side.

Declaration merging is not something good to work with.
In general you should almost never modify built in types/functions etc, since it may lead to unexpected behaviour.
If I was you, I would write my own types rather than using built in ones, it would give you flexibility and would not lead to unexpected behaviour.

There are cases - such as mine - where you cannot avoid built in types. An event listener receives an Event, MouseEvent etc builtin types.
Secondly, declaration merging does not change any behaviour - it is purely for typing.
For example, we make use of a deprecated API (because of old browsers) which is not documented and would cause an undefined symbol in typescript.
In that case we use declaration merging to define that symbol, and define it as "deprecated". Typescript won't complain anymore and we get type hinting (and proper deprecations).
